# Relation between multiplicative and additive identity in an ordered field

Tags: real-analysis, ordered-fields

In class, we prove that 1>0 by using order axioms of a field. The question is can we conclude that multiplicative identity is always less than the additive identity for any arbitrary ordered field?

Comment: As you mentioned, the multiplicative identity $1$ is greater than additive identity $0$, or I misunderstand you.

Comment: Was the thing proved in class a special case then (for instance $\mathbb R$)? If not then your question sounds a bit like: "if a statement is proved then can we conclude that we are dealing with a true statement?" Of course the answer on that is: "yes".

Comment: In class it is proved for R.

Answer (score 0):

You have $-x \le 0 \le x$ or $x \le 0\le -x$, and $0\le x^2$ for every $x\in k$. Choose $x=1$. Now $x=x^2\neq0$, so $0<1$.